# converting strings like annual bi annual to integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings like bi-annual (2 times in a year) or tri annual  or annual that i would like to assign values which is inside a bracket if a condition is met.

```
For example. lets say, `Frq = bi annual` , so i want to assign value 2 to frq.
If `frq = tri annual`, i want to assign value 3 to frq.
```

Any idea how i can do this?

PS. I dont want to use if. I want something like dict that contains `{'bi annual' : 2,'annual' :1}` and take value from these dict if conditions are met and assign to frq .

Comment: Use two `if`s and assign value to `frq`. Where do you get it wrong?

Comment: I dont want to use if. I thought of using it. I want something like dict that contains {'bi annual' : 2,'annual' :1} and take value from these dict and assign to frq  . P.S(if won't look good, as i got so many conditions )

Comment: @dhinar That's great! I suggest editing those thoughts into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want a map dictionary like so:

```
map_dict = {'bi annual' : 2, 'annual' :1}

frq = 'bi annual'
frq = map_dict[frq]
# frq is now 2
```

A much safer way is to use `get`. This guarantees that if value is not matching with `key` in `map_dict`, the original value is retained:

```
frq = 'bi annual'
frq = map_dict.get(frq, frq)
```

Comment: May i know why using get is safer ?

Comment: @dhinar see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'bi annual' : 2,'annual' :1, 'tri annual' :3}

s = 'Frq = bi annual'

sub = s.split('=')[1].strip()

frq = d[sub]

frq
2
```